# hMailServer doesn't let me send mail through Thunderbird - works with non-default port

Tags: smtp, port, timeout

I have hMailServer installed on Windows Server 2008. It's all set up and working, except that I can't send mail from it through Thunderbird (getting an SMTP timeout message) from my own PC (which is *not* in local network with the server). I have checked the settings multiple times, and they are correct. With a non-standard port (as in, not 25), I could send mail, but due to it being non-standard, those mails never got to the recipients.

Telnetting to the server through port 25 works. The ports are open from the firewall. Sending mail "locally" from the server works (and auto-reply works). My Thunderbird settings let me authenticate and send mail when the SMTP server is using a non-default port, but not when it's using 25, the default port. I can access other SMTP servers all fine through 25, and disabling my own firewall didn't help.

The exact error message is this (mind the Finnish at the start):

```
Postia lähetettäessä tapahtui virhe: postipalvelimen kättelyviesti oli virheellinen: Cannot connect to SMTP server 87.108.96.34 (87.108.96.34:25), connect timeout
```

Repeating, I can connect to it when the port is not 25. I do not have hardware firewall at the moment, which could prevent that.

Any help would be appreaciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, solved my problem. Apparently, my ISP *is* blocking the port 25, and I was using SSL and the port 465 with other mail servers. Added an additional (non-25) port for the SMTP server now, so that it can still communicate on 25 and the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Check your anti-virus/malware software (if you have any installed) which may be installed on the system. They have a tendency to intercept the common application ports in order to hijack them for their protection services.

Comment: I disabled my Anti-Virus and the server's Anti-Virus, but still can't send mail through that server. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: What is actually displayed when you telnet from the problematic system to the server on port 25?

Comment: 220 meili.ws ESMTP - and I can continue with e.g. HELO

Comment: Is that the exact same banner when you have things set for a non-SMTP port?

Comment: Yeah, it's the same one.

Comment: Ok, then you might consider trying some other email application for testing.

Comment: I actually found out my ISP _IS_ blocking port 25. Apparently, I was using SSL and the port 465 with other mail servers. Added an additional (non-25) port for the SMTP server now, so that it can still communicate on 25 and the new one. Thanks for the help, anyway!